# Open file browser at given path for browsing (not picking) 

Tags: android

Here is my scenario. My app downloads files from the internet and saves it into the users ExternalStorageDirectory . I would like to make my options menu button to work as a shortcut button to go to the downloaded files in `ExternalStorageDirectory`. Can anyone show me how it is done? Below are small parts of my codes.

I would like my options menu button to `onclick` and it goes to Absolute Path of my files. So users do not need to manually exit the app, and find it in the external directory.

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File dir = new File (sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Screenshots");


@Override
    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.select_text:

                SelectText();
                return true;
            case R.id.show_downloads:
                Intent i = new Intent();

            i.setAction(Environment.getRootDirectory);

            startActivity(i); //<<-- Here !!

                return true;
        }

        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }
```

I want my options menu button to go here.

[image]

Comment: I think you can display the files in a any view rather than going to the particular folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically in android you'd have an `Intent` `action` to popup an activity (or show show an activity chooser list) which can deal with that particular action. I had searched for such a solution some time back, but couldn't find an `Intent` which could simply open a file viewer to a particular path; you have the `action` `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` which can open the file browser, but as soon as the user clicks on a file, it returns to our activity.

So the solution I could think of was, get the list of files from your desired directory, and display it in your own application as, perhaps a `ListView`. Once the user clicks on an item, we can then continue to display the item with the `ACTION_VIEW`.

The reason I think android doesn't have such an option is, android doesn't have a default file viewer; one cannot be sure if there exists an application to view files in any given android phone. This is another reason why you should have the file viewer inside your application itself.